# 他のページの紹介文などの重複コンテンツをクリックイベントでDOM生成するのは、問題ないでしょうか？

Tags: javascript

他のページの紹介文などの重複コンテンツをクリックイベントでDOM生成するのは、問題ないでしょうか？

その後下記のような情報を見つけました。
この無限スクロールのように、別のhtmlファイルをスクロールイベントで、大本のhtmlファイルに非同期に読み込ませれば、クローキングになる可能性もほぼなく、かつ、大本のページには、追加したhtmlファイルの定型文は、存在しないようにクローラーは認識するので、重複コンテンツになる可能性もないと考えて良いでしょうか？
https://www.suzukikenichi.com/blog/how-to-configure-search-engine-friendly-infinite-scroll/

他のページの紹介文や、アプリの使い方の説明文など、どうしても重複コンテンツになってしまう部分を何とかしたいです。
下記のような情報を見たのですが、

> クリックによるDOM生成はページ遷移に該当するのでクローキング判定される可能性は低い。スクロールイベントに連動するものはガイドラインを厳格に適用すればクローキングに該当します。

つまり、スクロールイベントを使って、ある程度下がったらDOM生成して、他のページの紹介文などが作られる場合はクローキングになる可能性が高いので、やめたほうがいい。
しかし、リンクをクリックさせて、DOM生成する形で、テキスト情報を作成する場合は、クローキングになる可能性が極めて低いと考えて良いという情報です。

もしこれが正しければ、
他のページの紹介文を見るというページ内遷移のボタンを作ってこのボタンを押すと、
するっと移動しながらDOM生成して、到着と同時に作られた紹介文を見ることが出来るという形にすることが出来ます。

これなら、クローキングになる可能性はほぼありえないでしょうか？

一番の理想は、アプリのスタートボタンを押したら、紹介文などが、DOM生成する形です。
これなら絶対に、押すので、わざわざもう一度、紹介文を見るボタンを押してもらう手間が省けます。

ただこれだとクローキングになる可能性が高いのですかね？
いまいち、違いがわかりません。

・URLパラメータという方法もあるようですがこれは、サーバサイドのプログラミングをしないと不可能なのでしょうか？

フロントjsしかできない人には無理ですかね？

＊＊他の所では下記のように返信いただきました。

> 回答いたしますと、
>   クライアントサイド（JavaScriptでHTMLの内容を変えることも、クライアントサイドとなります。）で、いくら文面を変えようとも、
>   元のHTML文が同じ内容、構成であれば、いくらJavaScriptでリッチテキストでコントロールしようとも、
>   重複コンテンツとみなされる確率が非常に高くなります。（というかほぼ100%でしょう）
>   現在の技術では、ロボットのクロールの際の、サーバーから返ってきたHTML文章の内容で、 そのページの内容が判別されております。
>   である以上、ロボットが判断した後にいくらJavaScriptで内容を変えようが、Ajaxで別ページの内容を入れこもうが、重複コンテンツとみなされます。
>   よって、同じHTML上で、かつ重複コンテンツとみなされないようにするには、サーバーサイド（PHPとか、Perlとかです）で、URLパラメータなどによって判別し、
>   サーバーから返ってくるHTML文章の内容自体を変えるしかありません。 なので、クローキングの可能性云々ではなく、
>   JavaScriptでのリッチコンテンツは、検索エンジンロボットにとっては、”見えない内容”、なのです。
>   （見えないからこそ、下手なことをするとクローキングとみなされるのです）
>
> 検索技術の進歩を期待して止みませんが、
>   （現在は画像に書かれた文字を検索にひっかけるなどの技術が研究されています。そうなれば、JavaScriptの内容をも検索できる時代がいずれくるでしょう）
>   今のところは、質問者さんのやりたいことで、重複コンテンツ回避は不可能です。

Comment: マルチポスト - https://okwave.jp/qa/q9545812.html , https://teratail.com/questions/150855

Comment: 「問題」というのが「コーディング/プログラミング上の問題なのか」「SEO的な視点での問題なのか」を(マルチポスト先でも指摘されていますが)はっきりと強調した方がいいと思います。また、文書を引用される場合には出典のURLも併記しておいた方が親切です。SOでは文書の編集時に「ブロック引用」で括ることで該当箇所を強調できますので、併せて参考にしてください。

Comment: SEO的な視点です。ちゃんと他で聞いていると記載しています。

Comment: 「他で」がどこか、"回答しようとする人"には分かりません。「出典のURLを併記」するべきです。 https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 「このサイトの他の場所で役に立つ回答が見つからなくても、役に立たなかった関連するシステムのリンクを含めることで、あなたの質問が他のものとどう違うのかを他の人が理解するのに役立ちます。」

Comment: 理解了解しました。htｂ様のご意見